# What tense should be used for the verb "film"? Why?

Tags: verbs, tenses, past-tense, subordinate-clauses, esl

I was presented with this question on a test paper:

> _______(film) in various parts of China, Unexplored Land presents the great diversity of China's ecosystem and throws fresh light on the concept of harmony and a shared future between humans and nature.

I wrote "Being filmed" but it was incorrect. The correct answer was given as "Filmed".

Can anyone explain why this tense is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way to write the sentence is

> Unexplored Land, *which was filmed in various parts of China*, presents
> the great diversity of China's ecosystem...

However, the author has chosen to move this passive relative clause to the front of the sentence to give it greater prominence. To do so requires the clause to be elided (i.e. the words *which was* to be omitted).

You can now see why the "correct" answer is *filmed*.

Nevertheless, since the main verb of the first part of the sentence is *presents*, which is in the present tense, your suggestion of "*being filmed*" is acceptable if the filming is still ongoing - for example in a documentary series.

This is a common problem with decontextualised test questions.

Answer (score 0):

Being filmed is correct because that implies that it is continuous. The main difference is that being filmed means that they are still filming-in context- "the movie 'unexplored lands' is [currently -redundant information-] being filmed" vs. "the movie: 'unexplored lands' has [been-same reason-] filmed". For the aforementioned reasons, they are both right.

(forgive my poor punctuation, as I altered it from SWE to make a stronger-in my opinion- point)

*edited because I changed my stance mid-writing and realized it after I posted. Did not correct the accomplicing grammar, so the first sentence will look out of place.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Unexplored Land (which was filmed) in various parts of China, Unexplored Land presents the great diversity of China's ecosystem .... >> to reduce the relative pronoun you need to omit the be-verb as well.

Let's see what your answer would look like
While Unexplored Land (was being filmed) in various parts of China, Unexplored Land presents the great diversity of China's ecosystem...

It doesn't make sense because the first clause doesn't introduce  background information or simultaneous action.

I hope I didn't puzzle you even more.

By the way, obviously the process of filming has to be over and just then the film can present sth.